# Google Cloud Storage folder access denied 403 error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a google storage bucket with several folders containing images (png tile sets). The folders are set up identically, with all files shared publicly and read access given to all users.

I'm able to access the 2014 folder thru javascript in an app engine, both locally and in the cloud. However, when trying to access the 2015 folder i get errors like this on each file:

GET https://storage.googleapis.com/naip-skytruth-org/2014/9/142/193 403 ()

Access to both folders are identical with simple layering over a google map.
this.map.overlayMapTypes.push(this.selectMap(this.getSelectedNaip()))

Since permissions are kept at the bucket level, not the folder level, I'm not sure what to do next. I can list both folders using gsutil, and of course can go to the files on the cloud console to see that they're all shared publicaly.

What possible difference can there be in folder permissions? I understand ACL is no longer used.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the files in the tile set for 2015 folder had .png extensions, whereas the tile set for 2014 did not. So when the 2015 map overlay was selected, it couldn't find the files without the .png extension.

I'm not sure why it returned a 403 "Access denied" error. Should have been "file not found."

To fix, I wanted to simply remove the .png extensions but wasn't able to with gsutil. Ended up modifying the javascript to include a ".png" extension only for the 2015 folder/tile set.